# cygwin encoding problem

Tags: cygwin

I am puzzled at a cygwin encoding problem. I am using its Mintty 0.8.3. I copy and paste `⌊` or `⌋` character to the screen, it shows an un-recognizable character as a square, and if I hit return key, I got

`-bash: $'\342\214\212': command not found`

In options->text, I have set locale to be "en_US" and Character Set as "UTF-8".

Just wondering why this is still happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square means that the font you're using doesn't have glyphs for those characters, so try other fonts.

$'\342\214\212' is the UTF-8 code for one of those characters in octal notation, which is what bash uses in error messages instead of the actual characters.

Comment: @ak2: Are you sure it is the font problem? I am using Courier New on my cygwin's Mintty. I suppose Courier New should be able to display those characters, correct?

Comment: Unicode support in fonts varies widely, and support for mathematical symbols as you have there seems particularly spotty. One font that does support them is DejaVu Sans Mono.

Comment: @Warren, @ak2, yes, the font DejaVu Sans Mono does solve this issue. But I do not like the font. Hope that there is a way to add other fonts to cygwin.

Comment: This is not a Cygwin problem, it's a font problem. Fonts do not always have all characters defined in Unicode, and most fonts aren't fixed-width, suitable for terminal programs. It's not surprising that your choice of fonts is limited here. Maybe there is one out there more to your liking. MinTTY will use any TrueType or OpenType font that Windows can see. It would be up to you to find a font whose appearance you like and which also has all the characters you need.

Comment: @Warren, @ak2, this issue even occurs to my GNOME terminal 2.7.3 where no DejaVu Sans Mono font is available. What to do in this situation? thanks.

Comment: Ask a new question and hope for answers from people who know about GNOME terminal and whatever Linux distribution you're using.

Comment: Best to ask the question on http://unix.stackexchange.com, rather than here, however.